# Distance in polar coordinates

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polar-coordinates

It is
$$\sqrt{r_1^2 + r_ 2^ 2 − 2 r_1 r_2 \cos ( \theta_1 − \theta_2 )} $$
But how can the distance between two points $P_1,P_2$ be expressed in terms of components $  r_1-r_2$  and $\theta_1 − θ_ 2,$ just like the direct application of the cartesian distance from Pythagoras theorem?

Comment: You can't - the formula has it all.

Comment: Please read [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: I worked for a couple months at a place programming early car route. For a small enough region, actual distance can be approximated ( when latitude is almost constant) by a pretense such as you describe.   In the plane, just take a toothpick and drop it on a plane marked with polar coordinates, see how your desired quantities vary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer lies in this figure:

[image]

The two curvilinear rectangles are characterized by the same $\Delta\theta$ and $\Delta r$. But the lengths of the diagonals differ.

Comment: In fact, it already works with $\Delta r=0$.

Answer (score 0):

They can't. For instance, consider points with angle between them $\frac{\pi}{2}$, and with the same values of $r$ (such points exist, in cartestian coordinates, at $(r, 0)$ and $(0, r)$, among others). It is easy to see that the distance between these coordinates is $r\sqrt{2}$. Which depends on $r$.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a function of $r_1-r_2,\,\theta_1-\theta_2$ alone. In particular, if $\theta_1-\theta_2=\pi/2$ then $r_1-r_2$ doesn't determine $\sqrt{r_1^2+r_2^2}$, because that would mean it determines $r_1r_2$.

The problem is you need a third variable. The distance between $2$ points in $2$-dimensional space   may be rotationally invariant, but that only removes $1$ degree of freedom, leaving $2\times2-1=3>2$.